# Disabling footer in Wordpress theme stops sticky navigation being sticky

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, dreamweaver

I am using Dreamweaver to edit a child theme from WordPress. I want to change the footer or remove it completely. Currently, i have a copy of the footer.php file within my child theme and have commented out the code using /* */ to disable it for now and make it disappear from my site. Doing this has stopped the sticky navigation from working.

```html
</div><!-- end main-container -->
</div><!-- end page-area -->
<?php /* if ( is_active_sidebar( 'envo-blog-footer-area' ) ) { ?>      
 <div id="content-footer-section" class="container-fluid clearfix">
  <div class="container">
   <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'envo-blog-footer-area' ) ?>
  </div> 
 </div>  
<?php } ?>
<?php do_action( 'envo_blog_before_footer' ); ?> 
<footer id="colophon" class="footer-credits container-fluid">
 <div class="container">
  <?php do_action( 'envo_blog_generate_footer' ); ?> 
 </div> 
</footer>
<?php do_action( 'envo_blog_after_footer' ); ?> 
<?php wp_footer();  */ ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me what is causing the sticky navigation to stop working and also what is the best way to edit the footer?

Thanks

Comment: Don't remove `wp_footer();` That is a WP function to call in required code (scripts mostly)

Comment: don't comment out `wp_footer()` this is where your script is most likely placed

Comment: @yomisimie  JYNX - You owe me a coke!

Comment: @Stender Isn't that illegal? I prefer Pepsi

Comment: @yomisimie God have mercy on your soul, if you bring me a Pepsi! Keep that  `Sewage water` for yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are blocking the scripts that are included in footer thats why your sticky navigation is not working when you comment your footer code

Paste the below code in your footer an it will solve your problem

```
</div><!-- end main-container -->
</div><!-- end page-area -->
<?php /* if ( is_active_sidebar( 'envo-blog-footer-area' ) ) { ?>               
    <div id="content-footer-section" class="container-fluid clearfix">
        <div class="container">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'envo-blog-footer-area' ) ?>
        </div>  
    </div>      
<?php } ?>
<?php do_action( 'envo_blog_before_footer' ); ?> 
<footer id="colophon" class="footer-credits container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <?php do_action( 'envo_blog_generate_footer' ); ?> 
    </div>  
</footer>
// <?php do_action( 'envo_blog_after_footer' );  */ ?> 
<?php wp_footer();  ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the footer, they are some scrips running. You may disable/remove wp_footer(). The admin bar will not be shown in the frontend after admin logged in. I faced this issue.